# R: adding new column using lapply

Tags: r

I want to add a column to each dataframe of a list, where the values of two columns (col1 and col2) are concatenated

```
# create new column #
original.list <- lapply(original.list, cbind, new_column = c(""))
# add data to new column
new.list <- lapply(original.list, function (x) x$new_column = paste(x$col1, x$col2, sep = "_"))
```

However, this seems to be wrong since the result is a list with only the new column.

This is how each data frame of my original.list looks like

```
col1    col2
name1   1
name2   2
name3   3
```

This is how each data frame of my new.list should look like

```
col1    col2    new_column
name1   1       name1_1
name2   2       name2_2
name3   3       name3_3
```

Comment: You should probably provide a reproducible example here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your example is not reproducible, but if you want `x` and not just the new column maybe you should return `x` from the function...

```
 z <- data.frame(a=1:10)
 xlist <- list(z,z,z,z)
# wrong
 lapply(xlist, function(x) { x$b <- rep(8,10)})
#correct
lapply(xlist, function(x) { x$b <- rep(8,10);return(x)})
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure exactly what you're trying to do but it seems that you're simply trying to create a new column from two other columns in a data frame.  lapply is overkill for that. Try the following (assuming I understood the problem correctly):

```
new.list <- original.list
new.list$new_column <- paste0(new.list$col1, new.list$col2, sep="_")
```