# Adding dynamic column using lapply

Tags: r

Following on the [adding a column using lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877646/r-adding-new-column-using-lapply), I'm wondering if it's possible to add a dynamic column with `lapply`. I'd like to add a different value for the new column for each dataframe in the list:

```
z <- data.frame(a=1:10)
xlist <- list(z,z,z,z)
bvalues <- 1:4
```

In the question above, we added a constant value across all dataframes with

```
lapply(xlist, function(x) { x$b <- rep(8,10);return(x)})
```

To add the values dynamically from `bvalues`, I tried:

```
lapply(xlist, function(xx, ii) { xx[[ii]]$b <- bvalues[ii]; return(xx)})
```

But got the error

```
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  argument "ii" is missing, with no default
```

This seems to be a problem with having multiple inputs for the `lapply` call, but I can't figure out how to solve this. Here is my intended output:

```
[[1]]
    a b
1   1 1
2   2 1
3   3 1
4   4 1
5   5 1
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 1
10 10 1

[[2]]
    a b
1   1 2
2   2 2
3   3 2
4   4 2
5   5 2
6   6 2
7   7 2
8   8 2
9   9 2
10 10 2

[[3]]
    a b
1   1 3
2   2 3
3   3 3
4   4 3
5   5 3
6   6 3
7   7 3
8   8 3
9   9 3
10 10 3

[[4]]
    a b
1   1 4
2   2 4
3   3 4
4   4 4
5   5 4
6   6 4
7   7 4
8   8 4
9   9 4
10 10 4
```

Comment: you should definately do `Map(cbind,xlist,b=bvalues)`

Comment: Can you please post your expected output? If I'm correctly reading your intent, it seems like you're trying to make a replacement that doesn't do anything (i.e. replaces a 1 with a 1, a 2 with a 2, and so forth), so I suspect I'm not understanding what you're hoping for.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I have included intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `lapply()` function can be thought of as: "Break my list apart, and for each part do `fun` to it." So, the thing you want to break apart is not the list itself, but just the vector `1:4`:

```
lapply(1:4, function(xx) {xlist[[xx]]$b <- bvalues[xx]; xlist[[xx]]})
```

which gives your desired output if you want to go the `lapply()` route; note also that @Onyambu's comment

```
Map(cbind,xlist,b=bvalues)
```

also produces the same output.