# How to append a column to data.frames in a list where the column shall contain computationally read out structural information of those data.frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, append, lapply

I have some data that I read in and modify in R. For a minimal, reproducible example (reprex) I want to give the data as an "in R" representation to also communicate the data structure:

The code to read in the data:

```
paths <- sprintf("filenames%02d.out", 1:26)
interim <- lapply(paths, read.table, header=FALSE, sep="\t", dec=".", na.strings="NA")
new_col_name <- c("Pos", "LRTD")
out <- lapply(interim, setNames, nm = new_col_name)
```

Now, `lapply(out, head)` allows us to see R's internal representation of the data:

```
[[1]]
     Pos LRTD
1      0    0
2  70557    0
3 104076    0
4 163349    0
5 258229    0
6 356613    0

[[2]]
     Pos LRTD
1      0    0
2 171603    0
3 268756    0
4 456513    0
5 594904    0
6 663581    0

[[3]]
     Pos  LRTD
1      0 0.000
2 171960 0.370
3 217096 0.358
4 254484 0.338
5 320866 0.366
6 432642 0.382

{...}

[[26]]
     Pos LRTD
1      0    0
2 185161    0
3 234971    0
4 273218    0
5 319689    0
6 379800    0
```

So it is a `list` of `data.frame`s with 26 elements. Here, I want to call the numbers that we can see above in square brackets, so the numbers `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, `[[3]]` and so forth till `[[26]]`, as "element descriptors".

Now what I would like to do is append a third column to all the `data.frame`s in the `list` where the column contains computationally read out structural information of the `data.frame`s.
In detail, I would like to add the element descriptors of the given `data.frame`s to their respective `data.frame`. That in mind, the result should look like this:

```
[[1]]
     Pos LRTD   Chr
1      0    0   1
2  70557    0   1

[[2]]
     Pos LRTD   Chr
1      0    0   2
2 171603    0   2

[[3]]
     Pos  LRTD   Chr
1      0 0.000   3
2 171960 0.370   3

{...}

[[26]]
     Pos LRTD   Chr
1      0    0   26
2 185161    0   26
```

Since I am well aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877646/r-adding-new-column-using-lapply), my current solution is pseudocode:

```
lapply(out, function(x) { x$Chr <- rep("element descriptor","lenght of list");return(x)})
```

I know that I can get the length of the respective `data.frame` with `rapply(out, length)`, but so far I don't get `rapply` to work within my `lapply` command from above.

Also, how to reference the element descriptor in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map` works well for this.

```r
Map(function(x, ind) transform(x, Chr = ind), out, seq_along(out))
# [[1]]
#      Pos LRTD Chr
# 1      0    0   1
# 2  70557    0   1
# 3 104076    0   1
# 4 163349    0   1
# 5 258229    0   1
# 6 356613    0   1
# [[2]]
#      Pos LRTD Chr
# 1      0    0   2
# 2 171603    0   2
# 3 268756    0   2
# 4 456513    0   2
# 5 594904    0   2
# 6 663581    0   2
# [[3]]
#      Pos  LRTD Chr
# 1      0 0.000   3
# 2 171960 0.370   3
# 3 217096 0.358   3
# 4 254484 0.338   3
# 5 320866 0.366   3
# 6 432642 0.382   3
# [[4]]
#      Pos LRTD Chr
# 1      0    0   4
# 2 185161    0   4
# 3 234971    0   4
# 4 273218    0   4
# 5 319689    0   4
# 6 379800    0   4
```

If your "element descriptors" are really names, then replace that with

```r
Map(function(x, ind) transform(x, Chr = ind), out, names(out))
```

and it will do effectively the same thing.

If you're comfortable with `lapply` and want to know how this compares with that, then the equivalent `lapply` for that `Map` would be:

```r
lapply(names(out), function(nm) transform(out[[nm]], Chr = nm))
```

You can even code-golf it a bit, with

```r
Map(transform, out, Chr = seq_along(out))
Map(transform, out, Chr = names(out))
```

(both identical output to above). This happens to work because we can use named arguments in `Map` that are passed-through to the `f=` (function) argument, `transform` in this case.

---

Data:

```r
out <- list(structure(list(Pos = c(0L, 70557L, 104076L, 163349L, 258229L, 356613L), LRTD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), structure(list(Pos = c(0L, 171603L, 268756L, 456513L, 594904L, 663581L), LRTD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), structure(list(Pos = c(0L, 171960L, 217096L, 254484L, 320866L, 432642L), LRTD = c(0, 0.37, 0.358, 0.338, 0.366, 0.382)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), structure(list(Pos = c(0L, 185161L, 234971L, 273218L, 319689L, 379800L), LRTD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and especially your comparison with `lapply`! The comparison helps me to deeper understand the solution and your `Map` command worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `purrr` could be:

```
imap(out, ~ update_list(.x, Chr = .y))

[[1]]
     Pos LRTD Chr
1      0    0   1
2  70557    0   1
3 104076    0   1
4 163349    0   1
5 258229    0   1
6 356613    0   1

[[2]]
     Pos LRTD Chr
1      0    0   2
2 171603    0   2
3 268756    0   2
4 456513    0   2
5 594904    0   2
6 663581    0   2

[[3]]
     Pos  LRTD Chr
1      0 0.000   3
2 171960 0.370   3
3 217096 0.358   3
4 254484 0.338   3
5 320866 0.366   3
6 432642 0.382   3

[[4]]
     Pos LRTD Chr
1      0    0   4
2 185161    0   4
3 234971    0   4
4 273218    0   4
5 319689    0   4
6 379800    0   4
```

Comment: Also thanks for your answer. Though I have to admit that I personally like the "vanilla" answer without the need of further packages more.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all files have a similar structure, i.e., the order and types of columns are identical (the names may differ). Therefore, I hope you don't mind if I suggest a completely different approach which doesn't answer your actual question but may help to solve what I believe is the underlying problem.

In situations like this, my preferred approach is to combine all files *in one large dataset* where the source is indicated for each row in an id column (OP's *element descriptor* `Chr`).

So, here is what I would do using my preferred toolset

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) 
new_col_name <- c("Pos", "LRTD")
paths <- sprintf("filenames%02d.out", 1:26)
out <- lapply(paths, read.table, header=FALSE, sep="\t", dec=".", na.strings="NA") %>%
  rbindlist(use.names = FALSE, idcol = "Chr") %>%
  setnames(old = 2:3, new = new_col_name)
```

> ```
>     Chr    Pos  LRTD
>  1:   1      0 0.000
>  2:   1  70557 0.000
>  3:   1 104076 0.000
>  4:   1 163349 0.000
>  5:   1 258229 0.000
>  6:   1 356613 0.000
>  7:   2      0 0.000
>  8:   2 171603 0.000
>  9:   2 268756 0.000
> 10:   2 456513 0.000
> 11:   2 594904 0.000
> 12:   2 663581 0.000
> 13:   3      0 0.000
> 14:   3 171960 0.370
> 15:   3 217096 0.358
> 16:   3 254484 0.338
> 17:   3 320866 0.366
> 18:   3 432642 0.382
> 19:   4      0 0.000
> 20:   4 185161 0.000
> 21:   4 234971 0.000
> 22:   4 273218 0.000
> 23:   4 319689 0.000
> 24:   4 379800 0.000
>     Chr    Pos  LRTD
> ```

So, with all data in one large dataset, we can operate on whole columns without the need to call `lapply()` to deal with every chunk but we can group by or subset by `Chr` if necessary. This approach has simplified my workflows in many cases.

Comment: In fact, my next question would have been on how to concatenate `data.frame` list elements to one (big) single `data.frame`. Actually, I already tried to somewhat ask that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363835/how-to-iteratively-read-in-files-in-r-and-save-the-content-of-each-file-in-a-dif) though I could not really convey what I wanted to ask at that point.
So thank you for answering my concatenation question in advance!